# Javascript - how to compose asynchronous functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, functional-programming

I have this code:

```
const compose2 = (f, g) => (...args) => f(g(...args))
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce(compose2)

const count = arr => arr.length
const split = str => str.split(/\s+/)
const addAsyncWord = async str => `${str} some words obtained asynchronously`
const read = text => text


const word = compose(
        count,
        split,
        (await addAsyncWord),
        read
    )

console.log('word ->', await word()) //<- edited
```

but is throwing the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical
```

output expected after reading, concat words (obtained from a server randomly, needs to be asynchronously), spliting words, and finally count the total length, must be  something similar to this:

```
word -> 10
```

How to make this to work? thanks

Comment: From a purely functional agnle you can't. Function composition is based on a functor (of the function type). If you have to deal with async functions you need another type, namely continuations and the appropriate tools to compose them (applicative and monad).

Comment: Take a look at ramda implementation of `composeWith` and `andThen`:
https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/source

Comment: I'm not getting a syntax error from your code? But `word` is a function that you never call…

Comment: You'll need `const compose2 = (f, g) => async (...args) => f(await g(...args))`. An `await` in the arguments list of `compose` won't achieve anything, `addAsyncWord` is a function not a promise that can be waited for.

Answer (score 4):

I will post my solution here if helps anyone in the future:

```
const compose2 = (f, g) => async (...args) => f(await g(...args))
const compose = (...fns) => fns.reduce(compose2)

const count = arr => arr.length
const split = str => str.split(/\s+/)
const addAsyncWord = async str => `${str} some words obtained asynchronously`
const read = text => text

const word = compose(
    count,
    split,
    addAsyncWord,
    read
)

const test = async () => {
    const word1 = await word('Hello world')
    console.log('word ->', word1)
}

test()
```

thank you for your comments.

Comment: if you have more than one argument it could be rewrited as `const compose2 = (f, g) => async (...args) => f(...await g(...args))`